# Why is my python repeat function not working?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, repeat

Im trying to run a function that contains a stochastic simulation x multiple times. The first thing I've tried is to write a second function which contains a `for loop` to call the first function x times.

```
def repeat_func(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array):        
    """ A function to call the gillespie_tau_leaping x amount of times."""
    for i in range(10):
        popul_num_all, tao_all = gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)
    return popul_num_all, tao_all
```

I want to plot `popul_num_all` and `tao_all` on a graph x times. These are two `arrays` which are the returned objects from the `gillespie_tau_leaping` function. `popul_num_all` shows the changing molecule numbers (wants to be on the y-axis) and `tao_all` is the change in time as the simulation runs (wants to be on the x-axis).

Heres the code I'm using to produce the plots:

```
def gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num_all):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i, label in enumerate(['Enzyme', 'Substrate', 'Enzyme-Substrate complex', 'Product']):
        ax.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, i], label=label)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
    return fig
```

But in this current form the simulation only runs once and only one graph is plotted.

I know there are quite a few similar questions that are for things like recursion and lambda functions, but I can't get those solutions to work in my program.

Where am I going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop. Which means the loop runs only once

Comment: Unindent `return popul_num_all, tao_all`?

Comment: Good spot thank you, Its now changed (see edit) but unfortunately still runs in the same way

Comment: Seems that the loop runs 10 times but overwrites `popul_num_all, tao_all` each iteration.

Comment: Right okay, should I try use something like enumerate to label the output of each loop iteration?

Comment: You call the same function 10 times, giving it the same input each time. Even if you collected the results of each call separately, why aren't you expecting to just get the same results 10 times?

Comment: The function I'm calling samples random numbers and distributions etc, so I'm expecting them to be extremely similar but not identical.

Answer (score 2):

The "repeat_func" written by you returns popul_num_all and tao_all.
The reason why you are getting a single value for popul_num_all and tao_all is as explained below:

When i = 1, popul_num_all, tao_all = some array returned by gillespie_tau_leaping().
When i = 2, popul_num_all, tao_all = again an array returned by gillespie_tau_leaping().
So during every iteration, the variables popul_num_all, tao_all are updated and thus when you return these variables in "repeat_func", it returns the values during the last iteration only.
If you want to plot the graph during every iteration of for loop, then call the gillespie_plot function inside the loop.

Also, you are passing the same inputs to gillespie_tau_leaping() inside the for loop and hence even if you try to plot for all iterations the graphs will be similar.